# Automatic Height Dimension cell TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I configured a `tableview` with a dynamic height cell using `AutoLayout` as below (I precise that my constraints are right (top from bottom)). The content of my `tableview` is set with `Rx Binding`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

I tried to put a static estimated height which corresponds to the desire height row.
My `tableview` is inserted inside a `UIView` with all the constraints at 0 (`top, bottom, leading, trailing`) which I need to change the size to match that of the tableview.
I tried also to set the height constraint of my `UIView` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillAppear` but it doesn't work
However, when I arrive on the screen my UIView which contains my`tableView` doesn't have the right height because the row is smaller than it content.
I precise that I try to call the method `layoutIfNeeded` and It doesn't work. I noticed that if I called the `Rx binding` of my `tableview` again the size was correct.

Have you any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Searching comes up with many examples of "self-sizing table views." But, if you will only have a few rows in your table (which seems to be the reason to have a self-sizing tableView), you may want to use something other than a tableView -- such as a `UIStackView`.

Comment: For the moment, I have only one cell. However, I will implement other cells in the future.

Comment: I suppose you need to describe what you're trying to do with your layout. `UITableView` is designed to have a constrained height, and allow rows to scroll when there are too many to fit. It is unusual (and very often problematic) to try and do it "the other way around."